# MySQL - Duplicate entry for key XXX

Tags: mysql, sql

my only entries in table is:

```
SQL: SELECT * FROM `harmfull_hours` WHERE `date` >= '2014-06-01' LIMIT 0, 30 ;
result: 3
id  date        user_id        number_hours     
53  2014-06-01  00239 [->]     60
68  2014-06-01  00728 [->]     44
87  2014-06-01  oi0au1on [->]  54
```

and when i wanted to add row with this sql query

```
 INSERT INTO `kadry`.`harmfull_hours` (
   `id` ,
   `date` ,
   `user_id` ,
   `number_hours`
 )
 VALUES (
   NULL , '2014-06-30', '01325', '54'
)
```

i got this error `#1062 - Duplicate entry '01325' for key 'user_id_2'`
 i tried to find `user_id_2` but in `information_schema`

```
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA   CONSTRAINT_NAME     TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME          COLUMN_NAME     ORDINAL_POSITION    POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT   REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA     REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME   REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME  
def                     kadry [->]          user_id_2           def             kadry [->]      harmfull_hours  user_id         1                   NULL                            NULL                        NULL                        NULL
def                     kadry [->]          user_harm_id        def             kadry [->]      harmfull_hours  user_id         1                   1                               kadry                       users                       id
```

and i can't find any solution ?

Comment: there is unique key constraint for "user_id" column, so you are getting this duplicate entry error while inserting record with same user_id

Comment: oh my...  you are tight , i need holidays